# Compactness in $W^{1,p}_0(B_R)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

I have a sequence of functions $\{u_k\}_k \in u + W^{1,p}_0(B_R, R^N)$, where $B_R \Subset \Omega $ is the ball of radius R and $\Omega \subset R^n$ open and bounded, $u \in W^{1,p}(B_R, R^N)$.

I want to understand why $\{ u_k - u\}_k$ admits a subsequence that converges weakly to a function $u_{\infty} - u.$

Maybe the set $ W^{1,p}_0(B_R, R^N) $ is weakly compact, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false.

Let $u=0$ and let $v\in W_0^{1,p}(B_R,R^N)$ be a function with $\|v\|>0$.
Then define $u_k:=kv$.
Then it turns out that there is no weakly convergent subsequence of $\{u_k-u\}_k$
(this is because weakly convergent sequences must be bounded).

Comment: And if we suppose that $\{ u_k - u \}$ is bounded what happens?

Comment: @Fil Then we get a weakly convergent subsequence if the space is reflexive, which is the case for $p\in(1,\infty)$.

Comment: But  where does this result come from?

Comment: @Fil It is a consequence of the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem#Consequences

Comment: Thank you so much!